# Including index.html in a href

Tags: html

In the URLs for my website, I don't want to have index.html. For example, I want example.com/foo instead of example.com/foo/index.html

To accomplish this, I changed all of my navigation `href` to the following

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../foo/">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="../bar/">Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="../baz/">Baz</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Now, this works great on my live site. However, when I try to test my site locally, the URLs open up a blank page with the different files listed in the directory. Does anybody know why this is a good solution to test locally and also not have index.html appear on my site?

The following is what I see when I click on the navigation tab `Foo`. It takes me to this. However, on my live site, I get taken to the correct page, which is www.example.com/foo/

[image]

Comment: Using `httpd`? What's the value of your [`DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)?

Comment: Please consider rephrasing `"Anybody know why this is/a good solution to test locally and also not have index.html appear on my site?"` to be more clear.

Comment: @JasonAusborn sorry, edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz The site is hosted using Github Pages, and they don't allow .htaccess